# Error when adding new table on service.xml - Liferay 6.2

Tags: service, liferay, liferay-6.2

I'm using liferay 6.2 and I want to add a new table on service.xml.

The new entry on service.xml is:

```
<entity name="FeedError" local-service="true" remote-service="false" cache-enabled="false">

<column name="feId" type="long" primary="true" id-type="identity" />

<column name="errorCode" type="String" />

<column name="translation" type="String" />

<column name="facility" type="String" />

<column name="recordId" type="long" />

<column name="dateTime" type="Date" />

</entity>
```

Then, when running Build Service with Ant or Liferay Plugin, I got the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED

/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common-plugin.xml:443: The following error occurred while executing this line:

/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.2/build-common-plugin.xml:147: Service Builder generated exceptions.
```

Looking at build-common-plugin.xml:443 is:

```
439:    <build-service
440:     service.api.dir="${basedir}/${service.base.dir}/service"
441:     service.sql.dir="${basedir}/${service.base.dir}/sql"
442:     service.test.dir=""
443:     />
```

The error is only when adding a new entry to service.xml; for existing ones, it builds without any issue.

Any help is great appreciate!

Comment: I hardly remember that there was one an issue with the keyword "error" in table or column names. The service builder once greped for this keyword. You might give it a try to not use the word "error" in your column definition

Comment: I was about to write the same thought into an answer - now suggesting that you turn your comment into an answer, @AndreAlbert...

Comment: Thank you @OlafKock for the reply. Transformed my comment to a possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hardly remember that there was an issue with the keyword "error" in table or column names. The service builder once greped for this keyword. You might give it a try to not use the word "error" in your column definition.

Comment: hi Andre, that was the reason, you made my day :-) I just replace all "error" for another word, and I was able to build without issues, thanks a lot!